# Azure DevOps REST API: how to get release stage's test results?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I have a `Azure DevOps` release pipeline which contains 10+ stages (environments). Each release stage will run a set of test cases for example, BVT Test Stage, Performance Test Stage, etc.

Now, I would like to automatically query the test results from each of the test stage, by REST API.

I can use ["Runs" API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/runs/query?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to query the test runs for this release; I can use ["Release" API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/get%20release?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to query the release stages including their stage names.

But the problem is, I am not able to link the test result from the test run back to the release stage.

For example, I have release stages like "BVT Test", "Performance Test", etc. But the test result from test run is something like "VSTest_TestResults_2234523"

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> how to get release stage's test results?

Try with below api:

```
GET https://vstmr.dev.azure.com/{org name}/{project name}/_apis/testresults/resultdetailsbyrelease?releaseId={release id}&releaseEnvId={environment id}&api-version=5.2-preview.1
```

To get the test result of one specific environment, you must provide the `environment id`, along with its corresponding `release id`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is very useful! Some questions: 1) where is the link for the API 5.2-preview.1? I did not see it from learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/. 2) If the release pipeline (same pipeline) has been run multiple times, looks like this API will only return the first test result. How can I specify to make sure it return the latest results? Thanks so much!

Comment: @HowardShane. Sorry, it is the one we ever developed, but haven't documented and public to users. For your second puzzle, you need replace the environmentid and the releaseId if you want to get the latest test result. You know every test point to one specific pipeline. And every releaseid/environment id the pipeline generated would not same at all. You need replace them every time.

Comment: Thanks. If we "redeploy" the same pipeline, then it will not increase the release ID. the "stageID", or aka "environmentID" will not change either. So if I query the results based on those two parameters then I could have multiple results, right? The API you shared will not give me the latest result.

Comment: @HowardShane, Ohh, get it. But one issue you need confirm is does the corresponding integrated test actually re-run after you re-deploy the stage?

Comment: Yes, it will rerun as we want to "re-deploy" it.

Answer (score 0):

Each test run has a member points to the release's `environmentId`.

```
        $stageName = $stageTable[$($oneRun.release.environmentId)]
```